# Was ist eine übliche Weise, jemanden (im Internet) nach seinem Geschlecht zu fragen?

Tags: gender

Es ist mir schon vorgekommen, dass ich mich mit einer fremden Person im Internet auf einem Chat unterhalte, und manchmal weiß ich nicht, ob derjenige ein Mann oder eine Frau ist, und ich möchte danach fragen.

Mich interessiert, was natürlicher klingen würde:

> Bist du ein Mann oder eine Frau?

oder:

> Bist du weiblich oder männlich?

Ich habe das Gefühl, dass die erste Alternative ein wenig zu formell klingt, besonders wenn die andere Person vermutlich ziemlich jung ist (18-25 Jahre alt), und wir ganz freundlich und ungehemmt miteinander reden. Aber vielleicht ist es ein falsches Sprachgefühl, das ich habe.

Oder gibt es vielleicht eine andere, üblichere Weise diese Frage anzugehen?

Comment: Und wenn die Person weder noch ist?

Comment: Im chat einfach: bist du m/w/x?

Comment: Ich stimme für die Schließung: der sprachliche Teil ist geklärt, es bleibt nur Meinung übrig (was klingt natürlicher?) oder Etikette (wie gehe ich das an?).

Comment: Was die Etikette angeht, finde ich die Frage nach dem Geschlecht unangemessen und habe sie selber noch nie gestellt.

Comment: @Olafant Vielleicht schreibst du eine Antwort. Ist der 'x' eine Abkürzung?

Comment: @sermonionx x steht für *etwas anderes*, *irgend etwas dazwischen* oder *weder/noch* ...

Comment: Auch wenn die Frage auf Deutsch gestellt wurde könnte sie eher zu [interpersonal se](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com) passen.

Comment: @mtwde Nicht wirklich. Ich finde kein Problem daran, wie ich diese Frage auf Englisch stellen würde - "Are you male or female?". Ich wollte wissen ob das auch im Deutschen ("weiblich oder männlich") natürlich klingt.

Comment: Ich muss @DavidVogt zustimmen.

Comment: Ich stell die Berechtigkeit der Frage ja nicht in Abspruch, aber man sieht ja, dass die sofort in Richtung "Sollte man so etwas überhaupt fragen" abdriftet. Was evtl besser bei der anderen Seite aufgehoben wäre. Auch wenn da die meisten wohl eher den amerikanischen Blickwinkel drauf haben ^^

Comment: `asl` wird im Chat eigentlich überall genutzt, um solche Details zu erfragen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ich würde

> Bist du weiblich oder männlich?

nutzen. *Mann* und *Frau* implizieren auch ein gewisses Alter bzw. Status. Zum Beispiel würde ich männliche Menschen erst ab ~21 als *Mann* bezeichnen, da der Begriff eine gewisse Reife mitträgt. Außerdem können diese beiden Begriffe auch als Ehefrau/Ehemann verstanden werden.

Über weitere Geschlechtsempfindungen würde ich mir keine Sorgen machen. Sollte sich jemand aus dieser sehr kleinen Minderheit weder als Mann noch als Frau fühlen, kann er es dir einfach sagen und dann kannst du dich entsprechend darauf einstellen.

Answer (score 1):

Vor dem Hintergrund des mittlerweile [selbst vom Bundesverfassungsgericht anerkannten positiven dritten Geschlechts](https://www.bundestag.de/resource/blob/565996/50dee81f312fc665923f7068f834a8dd/WD-7-098-18-pdf-data.pdf) ("divers", gleichberechtigt neben "weiblich" und "männlich", vgl. zusammenfassend https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drittes_Geschlecht) kann es für das Gegenüber unter Umständen schwierig sein, eine binäre Geschlechtsdefinition "aufgezwungen" zu bekommen. Zudem ist - je nach Kontext - diese Frage möglicherweise irritierend, weil sie die Tonalität eines zuvor eher plaudernden, "unverfänglichen" Gesprächs in eine sexualisierte Richtung umlenken könnte (ob willentlich oder unbeabsichtigt). Daher ist das unter Umständen eine delikate Angelegenheit. Ich würde deswegen vermutlich auch nicht eine durch Verniedlichung ironisierende, humorvolle Variante wählen ("Bist du ein Weibchen oder ein Männchen?"), was mein erster Gedanke war, sondern vielmehr dem Gegenüber die Möglichkeit offen lassen, das schlicht nicht zu beantworten: "Wenn ich dir damit nicht zu nahe trete - darf ich dich aus Neugier fragen, welchem Geschlecht du dich zuordnest?" Ob es jedoch, wie du wissen möchtest, eine übliche(re) Weise gibt, diese Frage zu klären, weiß ich nicht. Als ich in der von dir genannten Altersspanne war, schrieb man oft einfach "ASL" (vgl. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Age/sex/location), und das war schon damals ziemlich plump. Insofern ist wohl alles besser, und sei es "Du, sag mal, bist du eigentlich ebenfalls männlich, oder eine Frau" (oder anders herum, je nachdem, was zu deiner Realität passt).

Comment: Die Antwort von einer Ausnahme, die vielleicht 1-2 Promille der Bevölkerung betrifft aufzuspannen, basierend auf einer wissenschaftlich unhaltbaren Standpunkt (drittes Geschlecht) halte ich für wenig hilfreich.

Comment: Einfach nur "bist du eigentlich (auch) ein Mann/eine Frau?", ohne die andere Alternative anzuhängen, halte ich für eine ausgezeichnete Lösung um sich aus der Problematik herauszuwursteln, und gleichzeitig weder jemandem zu nahe zu treten, noch nicht mit dem ensprechenden Diskurs Vertraute zu verwirren, noch der reaktanten Fraktion einen Angriffspunkt zu geben.

Comment: @userunknown Deine Behauptung einer wissenschaftlichen Unhaltbarkeit von Intersexualität ist unzutreffend. Möglicherweise vermischst du hier verschiedene Themenkomplexe (Intersexualität und Transsexualität z. B.), die teilweise sehr kontrovers diskutiert werden. Einen gut zugänglichen überblick bietet beispielsweise https://www.zeit.de/gesellschaft/2019-01/drittes-geschlecht-identitaet-zuordnung-auswirkungen-gesetz-faq. Und: Glücklicherweise leben wir in einer pluralistischen Gesellschaft, in der nicht nur die Mehrheit den Diskurs prägt, sondern vor allem auch von "Ausnahmen" Betroffene.

Comment: Ich bestreite nur, dass es **ein** drittes Geschlecht gibt und dass Geschlecht ein gut gewählter Begriff dafür ist. Es gibt zwei Geschlechter, die sich miteinander fortpflanzen können und eine Vielzahl an seltenen Abweichungen davon. Das ganze Divers zu nennen ist ein fauler Kompromiss, denn ein Einzelner kann natürlich nicht divers sein.

Comment: @userunknown Diese Sicht ist meines Erachtens heteronormativ und zugleich eine biologistische, irreführende Vereinfachung. Wir beide wiederum, du und ich, sind zwei Menschen mit offensichtlich sehr unterschiedlicher Ansicht zu einem Thema, um das in der vorgelegten Frage jedoch gar nicht geht. Ich möchte auch (und kann vermutlich) dich gar nicht überzeugen und ich glaube, dass eine solche Diskussion hier nicht hingehört. Daher lasse ich es damit bewenden und werde dazu nichts weiter schreiben. Du mögest gerne das Schlusswort haben, wenn sich das für dich andernfalls unrichtig anfühlt.

Comment: Heteronormativ? Was soll das bedeuten? Dass ich anderen eine heterosexuelle Lebensweise aufdränge? Weder habe ich irgendwelche Normen aufgestellt, noch geht es überhaupt um sexuelle Präferenz. Wenn Du Biologie als biologistisch diffamierst, mit welchem Ziel auch immer, bin ich auch raus aus der Diskussion. Aber tolle Kampfbegriffe hast Du auf Lager!

Answer (score -1):

Mir ist nicht genau klar, was *im Internet fragen* hinsichtlich der verwendeten Kommunikationsform (schriftlich, akustisch) bedeutet. In Schriftform würde ich die Standardabkürzung aus den Stellenanzeigen übernehmen:

> m / w / d ?

Comment: Ich habe geschrieben, dass man sich im Chat unterhält. Also schriftlich.

Answer (score -2):

Ich würde es mit *männlich* und *weiblich* versuchen, ist jedoch sehr direkt und persönlich wenn sich jemand nicht als eines der beiden empfindet...

In diesem Artikel (Englisch -> [How to Find Out a Person's Gender](https://www.wikihow.com/Find-Out-a-Person%27s-Gender) wird folgendes vorgeschlagen:

> "Welche Pronomen verwenden Sie?"

So kann der befragte mit "sie" oder "er" beantworten und lässt einwenig mehr Spielraum offen (im Gegensatz zu männlich/weiblich). Ich selber finde eine solche Frage jedoch *sehr speziell* und ungewohnt und würde bei männlich/weiblich bleiben.

Comment: Die Frage nach dem "Pronomen" ist im Deutschen unüblich und führt daher vermutlich oft (meist?) zu Verwirrung. Meine persönliche spontane Antwort wäre vermutlich: "Alle, ich verwende zum Beispiel Demonstrativ-, Possessiv- und Personalpronomen und andere." Davon abgesehen befürchte ich, dass eine nicht unerhebliche Anzahl an Gesprächspartnern nichts mit dem Begriff "Pronomen" anfangen könnte.

Comment: Für mich selbst verwende ich natürlich das Personalpronomen "ich". Von anderen möchte ich mit "Du" oder "Sie" angesprochen werden. Aber ich verwende natürlich alle Personalpronomen.